# Why am I able to run a Java file using the "java" program without first compiling using "javac"?

Tags: java, compilation

I have just started to learn JAVA, I am not from CS background. So far I have understood Java scripts needs two step compilation (compile time and Run time).  (javac File_name.java). This will create a .class file which is platform independent bytecode. Further if i Use (java File_name), it will execute the program. Recently I have notice if I simply use (java File_name.java), I am getting the output. Even I have checked my directory there is no .class file generated. Can anyone please explain why this is happening. If a bytecode is getting generated, then where can i find it?
Note: I have used the path for java.exe
[image: cmd.exe]

I tried ,<directory of source code> java File_name.java

I expected some errors

i got the output

Comment: You've used one step action added in recent JDK, `java File_name.java` implicitly compiles and runs the code if it has `public static main(String ... args)`. If you want to compile+run separately use "javac" then see .class files before running java on the classes.

Comment: So, in this case no bytecode will be generated? I mean I am sure it will be generated, but i can not access it?

Comment: Java is not a scripted language.  And Java, like many languages, needs to be compiled and then executed.  In this case by a virtual processor known as the JVM.

Comment: It still generates bytecode but keeps it in memory.

Comment: Now, I have understood the workings. Thank you..

Comment: See https://openjdk.org/jeps/330.

Comment: I re-opened this Question. The writing is not clear, but it does contain a specific reasonable question as to why running `java SomeClass.java` executes that class.

Comment: @BasilBourque I've just updated the title to be descriptive.  Refining the text is a bit more of an undertaking than I'm willing to get into right now.

Answer (score 2):

## Pave the on-ramp

In recent years, the Java team at Oracle has sought to ["pave the on-ramp"](https://openjdk.org/projects/amber/design-notes/on-ramp) to learning Java.

The goal is to get a new student running code quickly and simply, with the least impediments, the least learning, and the least cognitive leaps. Then build on that early positive experience with more learning and more concepts.

### Compile-and-launch single file source code

One part of this effort is [*JEP 330: Launch Single-File Source-Code Programs*](https://openjdk.org/jeps/330). This feature changes the behavior of [the `java` executable program](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/specs/man/java.html).

- Before Java 11, the `java` command only ran Java apps that had already been compiled from source code to [bytecode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bytecode).
- With this new feature in Java 11 and later, that `java` program switches to *source code mode* if you pass the name of a `.java` source code file. If that file contains a `main` method, that class is compiled. The resulting bytecode is cached in memory. Lastly, that bytecode’s `main` method executes.

That summary is an oversimplification. For full details, read [JEP 330](https://openjdk.org/jeps/330).

### Compile-and-launch multiple file source code

In Java 22, arriving late 2024, you will find this compile-and-lauch feature enhanced to work with multiple source-code files. See [*JEP 458: Launch Multi-File Source-Code Programs*](https://openjdk.org/jeps/458).

### Implied class & `main`

A related feature under development is reduction of the ceremony in a *Hello World* app.

This:

```java
public class HelloWorld {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello, World!");
    }
}
```

… becomes this:

```java
void main() {
    System.out.println("Hello, World!");
}
```

For details, see [*JEP 463: Implicitly Declared Classes and Instance Main Methods (Second Preview)*](https://openjdk.org/jeps/463).

Note that this work is basically ["syntactic sugar"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntactic_sugar). The rules of how Java actually works are *not* changing. The Java team is just changing the tools to make smarter assumptions in how to handle such simplified code.